# How can I put a dollar ($) sign in the output in java?

Tags: java

[System.out.printf(i +"%" + f +".2f\n", futureInvestmentValue(investment, rate/12, i));](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLCwB.jpg)

Comment: Please don't link to pictures of your code.  Copy the code and paste it into your question.

Comment: Put a `$` (inside a quoted string, of course) in your format string expression wherever you want it

Answer (score 0):

use String format like below use $ at required position:-

```
System.out.printf(String.format("$ %d %d",2,3));
```